# Angular 9: csv with Japanese characters received from backend not being downloaded properly

Tags: angular, csv

What I'm trying to achieve: when the user clicks on a download link, they receive a csv that has Japanese characters in it from a laravel backend which is created dynamically and then automatically downloaded to the users PC.

**Problem**: CSV file shows english characters and numbers correctly, but not Japanese characters.

**What I've tried**:

**Attempt 1**:

html:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="downloadTest()">Download</button>

<a id="download" class="hidden" [download]="csvFileName" [href]="downLoadURL"></a>
```

component.ts:

```
url: string = "http://hojin.ctot.jp/markets/CSV/S01_USDJPY.csv"



downloadTest(): void {
    this.apiService.getCSV(this.testurl).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.generateCSVDownloadLink("test.csv", data).then(result => {
          const downloadElement = document.getElementById("download") as HTMLAnchorElement;
          downloadElement.click();
        });
      }
    });
  }

async generateCSVDownloadLink(filename: string, csv: any) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF";
      this.downLoadURL = undefined;
      this.downLoadURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(csvContent + encodeURIComponent(csv));

      setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000);
    });
  }
```

apiService.ts

```
public getCSV(url: string, params?): Promise<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          Accept: 'text/csv',
        });
    return this.http.get(url, {params, headers, responseType: 'text'}).toPromise().then((response: any) => {
      return Promise.resolve(response);

    }).catch(this.handleError());
  }
```

**Attempt 2**: (apiService.ts is same, html same without  tag)

component.ts

```
downloadTest(): void {
    this.apiService.getCSV(this.testurl).then(data => {
      if (data) {
        const bom = new Uint8Array([0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]);
        const blob = new Blob([bom, data], { type: 'text/csv' });
        const aTag = document.createElement("a");

        aTag.download = "test.csv";

        if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
          // for IE
          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, aTag.download);
        } else if (window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL) {
          // for Firefox Chrome
          aTag.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          document.body.appendChild(aTag);
          aTag.click();
          document.body.removeChild(aTag);
        } else {
          // fail
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Outcomes are both the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution finally:

in the http.get, I changed the responseType to `responseType: 'blob'`

Then I removed the following lines

```
const bom = new Uint8Array([0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF]);
const blob = new Blob([bom, data], { type: 'text/csv' });
```

from the downloadTest function and downloaded the blob as it was.